# Javascript Google Chrome, code won't work?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
<script Language="JavaScript">

window.alert("Bennet's Used Auto Sales: 2010 Sales");  //window to display the text


var Aqs = prompt("Enter 1st Quarter Sales for 2010 :", "");  // prompts to have user input data 
var Bqs = prompt("Enter 2nd Quarter Sales for 2010 :", ""); // prompts to have user input data 
var Cqs = prompt("Enter 3rd Quarter Sales for 2010 :", ""); // prompts to have user input data 
var Dqs = prompt("Enter 4th Quarter Sales for 2010 :", ""); // prompts to have user input data 

window.alert("The Sales Figure for Quarter One is :" + Aqs);  //prompts that repeat the inputted number
window.alert("The Sales Figure for Quarter two is :" + Bqs);
window.alert("The Sales Figure for Quarter three is :" + Cqs);
window.alert("The Sales Figure for Quarter four is :" + Dqs);

var totSales = (Aqs+Bqs+Cqs+Dqs);   //adds together all inputted data 
var avgQSales = (totSales/4);  //averages all inputted data

window.alert("The total sales for the year of 2010 for Bennet's Used Auto Sales are :" + totSales);    // window to show the variable from above
window.alert("The average Quarterly Sales of 2010 for Bennet's Used Autp Sales are :" + avgQSales);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The new code is above, the windows display properly but the outcome of the arithmetic isn't correct and i can't tell why. My goal here is to have the user input 4 numbers and have those numbers added together, then averaged, and i need to display it.

Comment: check your developer tools console for errors - `document.write` is so old school javascript, it should be avoided

Comment: My teacher is making us use a textbook that is from 2011, and has 1/5 reviews throughout the internet.. thanks for the help!

Comment: `document.write()` has been considered bad practice since *long* before 2011. But if it is what your teacher expects then I guess you have to use it in some cases. Note that it should *not* be used to make changes to the page after the page is loaded, so don't use it within event handlers.

Comment: You're ignoring the return values from `prompt()`, when you should be assigning them to variables like `var Aqs = prompt("Enter something");`. And you need to remove the semicolons from in front of the equal signs for `totSales` and `avgQSales`.

Comment: `var Aqs = parseFloat(Aqs);` doesn't make sense. What do you expect the value of `Aqs` to be?

Comment: Here is what i have now..

Comment: My exact hw question is this : You have the ﬁnal sales ﬁgures for the four quarters in 2010 for Bennet’s Used Auto Sales, and you are to design a program that asks for the sales ﬁgures,computes the total sales for the year, and calculates and displays the average quarterly sales for the year.

Answer (score 1):

Change line three to

```
<script>
```

In chrome dev tools (F12) click on Console. Refresh the page. You'll see where you have misplaced semicolons (lines 23,24). Fix your variables assignment. Javascript prompts return a value, which unless passed to a variable or method, they just disappear.

Note that your page will not finish loading until the prompts are completed. Your code will work as intended. But there is nicer implementation to be done by allowing the page to load, firing the prompts, then writing the results to the page via the Document Object Model in some particular place such as in http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_html.asp .

Edit: You may want to use document.writeln instead. This places a newline character /n at the end of each line, that way your DOM writes don't display as all in one line.